# Android Proguard submodule mapping

Tags: android, android-proguard

I am using Proguard in order to release an obfuscated version. In my project I have 2 submodules which are also my own libraries. Where can the mapping files be found?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify location for mapping file by specifying it in your project's proguard file

```
-printmapping build\outputs\apk\out.map
```